# Variants to PowerPoint for math paper presentations?

Tags: math-software

For a math talk, typing equations in PowerPoint is a really painful process, and yes, it's very far from the beautiful layout of LaTeX.

Is there a FREE non-PowerPoint software which I can use to create a nice talk which has support for LaTeX?

Comment: Beamer class for $\LaTeX$ might be what you're looking for!

Comment: There is a package called beamer in LaTeX that is designed for presentations.

Comment: Gee. Thanks Kannappan. What did they serve for breakfast today? :D

Comment: @KoundinyaVajjha I didn't take breakfast here today

Comment: I sent you a sample. Here is a good talk: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yL_-1d9OSdk

Comment: I am using LaTeXit in Os X but I am sure similar programs also exist for Windows and Linux. It allows to drag and drop LaTeX formulas into presentations.

Answer (score 7):

[Beamer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamer_%28LaTeX%29) is very powerful, and (after the usual learning curve) easy to use.  Looks good, too!

After unsatisfactory experiences with earlier LaTeX presentation tools, I have used Beamer (for contest typesetting) without too many headaches for a few years.

Answer (score 1):

As Andre has pointed out, Beamer is a "classical" way in which presentations are made for a math talk. It looks cute.

[Here](http://www.math.umbc.edu/~rouben/beamer/quickstart-Z-H-3.html#node_sec_3) is a very quick guided tour of how to use this package. (This link was found on the Wikipedia!)

[Here](http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/prosper/1/latexpre.pdf) is a tutorial that talks about other ways of preparing slides using $\LaTeX$ for a seminar talk.

But having said this, I prefer giving a talk on the black board, and handing out notes for the talk.

P.S.: If the task is to be accomplished pretty quickly, you may resort to searching for a template. Ask Prof. Google and he seems to know pretty good templates!

Comment: @Downvoter Care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

Beamer in $\LaTeX$ is obviously the standard for this kind of thing (I'd also suggest TexStudio), especially if it is mostly math on the slides, but I thought I would mention some nice, newer alternatives.

- Use Powerpoint or [Slides](https://slides.com/), but don't go through the nightmarish experience of typing the math; just export the equations (say from [this nice editor](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)) and import them into the slideshow. Then manipulate them like images, which those programs are much better at.
- Beautiful presentations can be done with Javascript (e.g. using [reveal](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/) or [deck](http://imakewebthings.com/deck.js/)) with mathematical typesetting via [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) (i.e. $\LaTeX$ for the web). (e.g. see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332660/writing-mathematical-presentations-using-mathjax?rq=1)). This gives the added bonus of being able to upload your presentation to the internet instead of carrying it around, and run it in a web browser anywhere, anytime, but you still get to basically just type $\LaTeX$ (in the HTML). Also, no more issues with animations failing in certain PDF viewers, compatibility with versions of Powerpoint, etc...